# Google Safe Browsing database generation

Tags: safe-browsing

During these days I would investigate about the `mod_security` integration with Google Safe Browsing but I can't generate the local GSB database with the HTTP call. Firstly I generated an API Key related to my Google user and if I tried to call the URL to retrieve the lists all works.

```
http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/list?client=api&apikey=<myapikey>&appver=1.0&pver=2.2
```

After that I generated the new MAc KEY over ssl call as reported below:

```
https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/newkey?client=api&apikey=<myapikey>&appver=1.0&pver=2
```

I received a 200 responde with a clientkey (length 24 chars) and a wrappedkey (length 100 chars). After that I tried to download the list with the call below, but I received a 400 response.

```
http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/downloads?client=api&apikey=<myapikey>&appver=1.0&pver=2.2&wrkey=<mywrappedkey>.
```

Did someone find the same behavior?